# How to perform sequential read in procfs?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, procfs

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/jiffies.h>
#include <linux/seq_file.h>

//extern uint64_t interrupt_time;

static struct proc_dir_entry *test_dir;

static int my_proc_show(struct seq_file *m, void *v)
{
    seq_printf(m, "%lu\n", jiffies);
    //seq_printf(m, "%lu", interrupt_time);
    return 0;
}

static int my_proc_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    return single_open(file, my_proc_show, NULL);
}

static const struct file_operations tst_fops = {
    .open       = my_proc_open,
    .read       = seq_read,
    .llseek     = seq_lseek,
    .release    = single_release,
};

static int __init test_init(void)
{
    test_dir = proc_mkdir("myproc", NULL);

    if (test_dir)
            proc_create("jiffies", 0, test_dir, &tst_fops);

    return 0;
}
static void __exit test_exit(void)
{
    remove_proc_entry ("jiffies", test_dir);
    proc_remove (test_dir);
}
module_init(test_init);
module_exit(test_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Test");
```

The above code is for procfs driver in which the above code contains the init function, exit function, file operation function but how to create a `seq_read()` function from kernel to user. What is the API for that?

This is the code I modified in `/linuxversion/net/core/dev.c`

```
int netif_rx(struct sk_buff *skb) 
{
  skb->tstamp = ktime_get_real();   //this will give a timestamp and it will be stored in //skb buffer
  //I am calculating a timestamp here. because whenever kernel receive the data then the kernel is 
  //interrupted and start executing the newly arrived task but I have to read the time when the 
 //interrupt  occurs and get the value of it.
}
```

My question is: **How to copy this time-stamp to `procfs`?**

Comment: `seq_read` is already implemented by the seq_file interface. Do you need to override it?

Comment: then how to read it to the user application ?? If I am reading some value(timestamp) then how should I read that value to the user application ??

Comment: Have you tried `cat /proc/myproc/jiffies`?

Comment: yes . I  got the value there. If I do like above then I dont need any other apis like copy_to_user (is this right ?) but how to read this value on the user application ??  another question : i modifed my code above and my question : HOW TO COPY THE TIMESTAMP TO PROCFS ??  I asked so many times regarding this and did not get any reply.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your issue is how to create and populate entries in `/proc` or how to read from an existing one. Regarding the latter:

> how to read it to the user application

From the user program open `/proc/foo/bar` and read from it, as from any other file.

Comment: If i use tha above code the I dont want any other api like copy_to_user. Is this right ??

Comment: Yes, the kernel writes to `/proc/foo/bar` (using code like from your question) and the user program reads from `/proc/foo/bar/` using for example `fopen()`. @user3458454

Comment: thank you very much. I modified my code and asked one more question. could you please answer that ??  I want to read the timestamp from kernel source code and read or sent it to user application.